# How to correctly import an img using HTML?

Tags: html, eclipse

This is what I have...

```
output.println("<p>""<img src="brush.jpg" alt="brush" width="500" height="400"></img></p>");
```

I have my "brush.jpg" in my source folder but for some reason, I am getting an error. The syntax error isn't being helpful either.

What could I be missing?

Comment: put the whole string in `'` single quotes instead. `'<p><img src="brush.jpg" alt="brush" width="500" height="400"></img></p>'`

Comment: I tried this, and it was a good suggestion but it didn't seem to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if it has something to do with you closing the quotes right after `<p>`?

Try:

`"<p><img src = 'brush.jpg' alt='brush' width='500' height='400'></img></p>";`? inside `println()`?

Comment: @Jenn - No problem! Don't forget to mark an answer as correct also using the checkmark ;)

Comment: I don't see where the checkmark is at? - Im a new user. Where is it?

Comment: Should be grey under the up-vote down-vote if you click it it turns green

Answer (score 0):

Your whole image location will target like this

Comment: if you can  give more detailes for you answer